# WooCommerce output metadata and functions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, custom-taxonomy

I want to change the output of the metadata, I want to delete the Reference, and I need to display the name of the subcategory of this product and the description of this subcategory.  tell me how it can be done.